# Transferring a file between two remote servers from a third server with excluding certain files

Tags: ssh, scp

Assuming there are folders and files like below

```
/master1/dir1/dir1_1/file1
/master1/dir1/dir1_1/file2
/master1/dir1/dir1_1/file2
/master1/dir1/dir1_1/file2
/master1/dir1/dir1_1/file2
/master1/dir1/dir1_2/file1
/master1/dir1/dir1_2/file2
/master1/dir1/dir1_2/file2
/master1/dir1/dir1_2/file2
/master1/dir1/dir1_2/file2
/master1/dir2/dir2_1/file1
/master1/dir2/dir2_1/file2
/master1/dir2/dir2_1/file2
/master1/dir2/dir2_1/file2
/master1/dir2/dir2_1/file2
/master1/dir2/dir2_2/file1
/master1/dir2/dir2_2/file2
/master1/dir2/dir2_2/file2
/master1/dir2/dir2_2/file2
/master1/dir2/dir2_2/file2
```

I have a terminal server from where password-less authentication is enabled for all the servers in my landscape and I would like to transfer files from one server to another.

When I run SCP with -3 option on the terminal server I was able to copy the files from one server to another and now I have to exclude certain files with file name `file1` or under directory `dir1_1`

I am using the below command inside a Perl script to copy all the files

```
scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -3 -v -r $srcHostname:$srcPath/* $tgtHostname:$tgtPath
```

In rsync I was unable to get a similar option like (scp -3) so i need to use only scp

how do i exclude a file pattern in SCP

Comment: Unfortunately, `rsync` doesn't support copying between two remote hosts.

Comment: If the command takes a list of files, as opposed to a glob, you could just construct the list in Perl, deleting unwanted file names, and supply it to the command. Or failing that, you could create a loop around the command and copy files one at the time.

Comment: Not a valid solution but you may want to take a look at this: `$srcPath/*/dir1/!(dir1_1)` this copies sub directories of `dir1` apart from `dir1_1`. However it does not create `dir1` in target directory so you need to do it like this `$tgtPath/dir1`...

Comment: There's also `ssh host1 rsync [options] files host2`